# Can somebody help me translate this into postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to SQL and I do not know much about writing code in the different DBMS. I am trying to write a report in our school's MOODLE platform, which uses postgresql, using a configurable report found [here](https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/ad-hoc_contributed_reports#User.27s_accumulative_time_spent_in_course). However, the code does not work in postgresql. In particular, how do I rewrite those lines with variable assignments like `@prevtime :=` to make the code work in postgresql?

Here is the complete code from the link.

```
SELECT 
l.id, 
l.timecreated, 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated),'%d-%m-%Y') AS dTime,
@prevtime := (SELECT MAX(timecreated) FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log 
        WHERE userid = %%USERID%% AND id < l.id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) AS prev_time,
IF (l.timecreated - @prevtime < 7200, @delta := @delta + (l.timecreated-@prevtime),0) AS sumtime,
l.timecreated-@prevtime AS delta,
"User" AS TYPE
 
FROM prefix_logstore_standard_log AS l, 
(SELECT @delta := 0) AS s_init 
# CHANGE UserID
WHERE l.userid = %%USERID%% AND l.courseid = %%COURSEID%%
%%FILTER_STARTTIME:l.timecreated:>%% %%FILTER_ENDTIME:l.timecreated:<%%
```

This is supposed to report the time spent by students in courses in MOODLE.

Comment: In SQL, a "program" consists of a single statement. There are no variables or assignments. There is no procedural processing and execution thread. You more or less describe the desired result and let the database work out the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the original query was written for MySQL. You haven't explained what the query actually does, but the `@prevtime` hack is usually a workaround for missing [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), so most probably this can be done using `lag()` in Postgres, something along the lines:

```
select l.id, 
       l.timecreated, 
       to_char(to_timestamp(l.timecreated), 'dd-mm-yyyy') as dtime, 
       lag(timecreated) over w as prev_time,
       l.timecreated - lag(timecreated) over w as delta,
       'User' as type,
FROM prefix_logstore_standard_log AS l
window w as (partition by userid order by id) 
WHERE l.userid = %%USERID%% 
  AND l.courseid = %%COURSEID%%
```